# How to handle long worker threads in enterprise environments

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Colleague of mine contacted me asking if it is possible to stop HTTP workers if the request takes to long. I have to admit, I found the question quite odd, and really not befitting for a service-based environment, but it got me thinking.

If you have large requests that really can take a long time to complete (> 5 secs e.g.) how could you stop them when you want to avoid your server from being swamped?

For reference: I'm using Glassfish v2.1.1. But general helpful comments are also appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timing out a http request is web container specific. For example for JBoss you can find more info [here](http://community.jboss.org/thread/39182) but if you expect that behavior it would be better to redesign your architecture to handle the calls asynchronously (maybe with MDB's)

Comment: Note that that thread ends with the same, open question: "But they do not stop the execution within JBoss I assume. In fact, is there any way JBoss can stop execution of a timed-out request?"